library request error when working in a while
The purpose of the code below is to periodically send requests and act depending on the response received.
while True:
    domain_type = requests.get(f'https://postmaster.mail.ru/ext-api/stat-list/?date_from={current_date}',
                               headers={"Bearer": token}).text

    res = json.loads(domain_type)
    domains = res['data']
    for i in range(len(domains)):
        if domains[i]['domain'] in list_to_check:
            domain_now = domains[i]['domain']
            host = f'http://{domain_data[domain_now]["host"]}:8486/v1/pauses'
            token = domain_data[domain_now]["token"]
            a = domains[i]['spam_percent'] + domains[i]['probably_spam_percent']
            if a > 3:
                print(f'У домена {domain_now} % спама составляет {a}. Отправляем на заглушку.')
                headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
                data_to_post = {"mta": domain_data[domain_now]["host"]}
                result = requests.post(host, headers=headers, json=data_to_post)
                list_to_check.remove(domain_now)
            else:
                print(f'У домена {domain_now} % спама составляет {a}. Пока ничего не далаем..')
    if len(list_to_check) < 1:
        break
    time.sleep(30)
print(len(list_to_check))

This is the first time I've received a complete answer. But when I request again, I get an empty response.
I read about closing sessions, but maybe I'm doing it wrong? Either way it doesn't help.
